# Sencha Touch 2 vbox and height of children

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I'm having problems trying to understand formatting a vbox in Sencha Touch 2.  My goal is to have each child to be full height (flex divides the screen in portions).  To keep it simple, I have a detail view that shows one record data, then a list of items that correlate to that record.

Right now, using flex, each child is a set height and scroll themselves.  I want them to be full height and the parent only scroll.  If I take the flex out nothing shows up.

```
Ext.define('app.view.MainView', {
updateData : function(data) {
    var panels = this.query('panel[tpl]'),
        pLen = panels.length,
        panel;

    for ( p = 0; p < pLen; p++) {
        panel = panels[p];

        panel.setData(data);
    }

    this.callParent(arguments);
},
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'mainView',
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox'
    },
    scrollable: true,
    title: '',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            flex: 1,
            scrollable: true,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<div class="view-top" id="view-{id}">' +
                '<div>{body}</div>' +
                '</div>')
        },
        {
            xtype: 'component',
            cls: 'dark',
            html: 'Top View'
        },
        {
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'list',
            store: 'ViewStore',
            variableHeights: true,
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>{subject}</div>'
            ]

        }
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution, for those of you who may land here with the same issues I will post solution.

Basically I had to count the height of each list element after the view was painted and then set the height of the id for the list to that new height (NOTE: I had to add the itemcount + 5 to the total height to accommodate for each item)

```
Ext.define('app.view.ViewMain', {
updateData : function(data) {
    var panels = this.query('panel[tpl]'),
        pLen = panels.length,
        panel;

    for ( p = 0; p < pLen; p++) {
        panel = panels[p];

        panel.setData(data);
    }

    this.callParent(arguments);
},
extend: 'Ext.Container',
xtype: 'viewMain',
config: {
    layout: {
        type: 'vbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },
    scrollable: true,
    title: '',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            height: 'auto',
            scrollable: null,
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate',
                '<div class="guest-top" id="view-{id}">' +
                '<div>{body}</div>' +
                '</div>')
        },
        {
            xtype: 'component',
            cls: 'dark',
            html: 'Guest Panels'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            id: 'panelList',
            store: 'ViewStore',
            height: 1000,
            scrollable: false,
            variableHeights: true,
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>{subject}</div>'
            ]
        }
    ],
    listeners: {
        painted: function(element, eOpts){
            var totalHeight = 0;
            var items = Ext.getCmp('panelList').getViewItems();
            var itemsLn = items.length;
            for (i = 0; i < itemsLn; i++) {
                item = items[i];
                totalHeight = totalHeight + item.element.dom.clientHeight;
            }
            Ext.get('panelList').setHeight(totalHeight + itemsLn + 5);
        }
    }
}});
```